# Getting data by value from sqflite

Tags: sqlite, flutter, dart, sqflite

I want to get data by a specific value only from sqflite and I don't know how query should look like. Any help would be nice.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you give an example of you table design, some test data and show us what value you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you said here, it sounds like you just need an introduction to basic queries? The following is a quick tutorial on SELECT - WHERE statements. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp

Comment: Thanks. That's what I needed 

Comment: @Artur no worries. Would you please mark this as the answer if it was all you needed.